# extracting from specific areas using pdfclown

Tags: java, pdf, pdfclown

I am trying to highlight text in PDF with two columns and but the problem is while the extractor extracts the text row wise. So the queried text doesn't get matched.
I was thinking if there is some function in `pdfclown` which can help me to extract first half of the page i.e., first column and then the second one probably by selecting the areas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you talk about text extraction with PDF Clown, I assume you are using the `TextExtractor` class of that library.

This class offers numerous attributes helping to restrict the parsing area:

```
public void setAreas(List<Rectangle2D> value);
public void setAreaTolerance(double value);
public void setAreaMode(AreaModeEnum value);
```

`setAreas` allows you to set the page areas to extract text from, `setAreaTolerance` allows you to add some tolerance to these areas (essentially enlarging the areas by this value in all directions), and `setAreaMode` is used to control whether a string must be *contained by the area* (`Containment`) or merely needs to *intersect the area* (`Intersection`) to be included in the scan results.

How these attributes work, can be witnessed in the `TextExtractor` method

```
public Map<Rectangle2D,List<ITextString>> filter(
    List<? extends ITextString> textStrings,
    Rectangle2D... areas
);
```

which filters the list of all text strings on the page.

Comment: what should be the arguments in setarea to select first column of the page?

Comment: I assume you know the coordinates of the rectangle defining that first column. Simply create a `Rectangle2D` instance with those coordinates and use a list containing only that entry.

Comment: rectangle2d is an abstract class how can I create its object and initialize it with the known coordinates?

Comment: `Rectangle2D` contains two non-abstract inner classes derived from `Rectangle2D:` `Rectangle2D.Double` and `Rectangle2D.Float;` use one of them.